# Using Audio tag with Android 4.x and Phonegap does not work

Tags: android, html, cordova

I have the below html page that was added to a newly created PhoneGap 2.9 project.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

       var onDeviceReady = function () {

      var ctrl = $("#smAudio").get(0);
       ctrl.play();
    };
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

  <audio id="smAudio" controls="controls">
    <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
  </body>
</html>
```

Upon loading of the page i get:  `08-20 16:18:13.152: E/MediaPlayer(3154): Error (1,-1004)`

If i hit the Play button on the controls, i get this weird error:

```
08-20 16:19:11.664: E/MediaPlayer(3154): Attempt to perform seekTo in wrong state: mPlayer=0x0, mCurrentState=1, e=1
08-20 16:19:11.664: E/MediaPlayer(3154): error (-38, 0)
```

Again this is a clean 2.9 project newly created from the `create` command line.  The phone is a Nexus S with Android 4.1.2.   If anyone can show me how to get this going, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the audio tag but I've had success using: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.9.0/cordova_media_capture_capture.md.html#capture.captureAudio